# The api controller in mvc can't be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to develop a `webapi+angularjs+mvc` project .here you can see my `apicontroller`

```
 public class DefaultController : ApiController
    {
        testDBEntities a = new testDBEntities();

        public IEnumerable<City> Get()
        {
            return a.Cities;
        }
    }
```

Here you can see the `webapiconfig`

```
   public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

        }
    }
```

But when i type this : `localhost:5411/api/default`

i got this error :

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /api/default
```

Comment: What version of WebApi are you using?

Comment: @AlexArt. how can i find the version ?

Comment: Always use {action} in your route path like - routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}". This is because, if you don't specify {action} you can't have multiple get methods in your controller

Comment: @KarthikMR i use this url http://localhost:20713/api/default/get but same error

Comment: So your action would be public                                                          [HttpGet]                                                                                       IEnumerable<City> GetCities()
        {
            return a.Cities;
        }

Comment: check `packages.config` file for `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` package version

Comment: @AlexArt.   <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net452" />

Comment: @KarthikMR same error

Comment: Try reinstalling the WebApi nuget package.

Comment: @Ehsan Akbar - Are you able accessing Help page ?

Comment: is this line present in global.asax.cs file?GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);

Comment: @KarthikMR thank you it works

Comment: @KarthikMR i don't know why the vs studio doesn't add this line to global by default

Comment: Since you have create only mvc project

Comment: @Karthik M R, WebApi has `Startup.cs` instead of `global.asax.cs`

Comment: Startup.cs file is created when you have token based authorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the line

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) in your Global.asax.cs file
```

And this will register the webapi routes

Comment: WebApi has `Startup.cs` instead of `global.asax.cs`

Comment: @Alex, when creating a new project, when both mvc and webapi is selected only global.asax is added, not Startup.cs

Comment: @AlexArt. i can't find  GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register) in the startup.cs